# Usage of participle and contemporary actions

Tags: participle

In this sentence: "Женщина, читающая книгу, жила в Москве", could you please tell me which is the correct interpretation?

- "the woman, that is now reading a book (I see her right now doing it), used to live in Moscow (some time ago)." The two actions are on two different time levels

or

- "The woman that was reading a book (also) lived in Moscow." It's like both actions happen at the same moment and both happen in the past. It's like I'm telling a friend about an  encounter I had with this woman, who, at the moment I met her, was reading a book and was also living in Moscow.

Comment: The first interpretation is correct as the participle "читающая" is in present tense.

Comment: I have this doubt since on the notes I took in my russian class I wrote: "present or past active participle + main verb in past tense = actions take place at the same time"...maybe I got it wrong.

Comment: There are two main types of participles - _страдательные_ and _действительные_. I guess they could be called _passive_ and _active_ in English. I can imagine passive (страдательные) participles in present form referring to past actions: _Гонимый_ ветром мяч упал в воду (А ball that _was driven_ by the wind fell into the water). But as for active participles (which "читающая" is), I expect same tenses.

Comment: Yes, you may have got it wrong. The participle must agree in time with the verb. In order for the sentence to mean that the two actions take place at the same *present* time it should read: *Женщина, **читающая** книгу, **живёт** в Москве*. The past time requires *Женщина, **читавшая** книгу, **жила** в Москве* (see @UVV's answer).

Comment: @Vilmar This has nothing to do with a type of participle, only with a tense

Comment: @UVV Ok, then give me an example of an active participle used in the present tense and main verb in the past tense that refer to the past, if you say there is no difference between the participle types.

Comment: @Vilmar I guess what you are asking is the sentence TS asked about. The difference in participle types would be only suffixes, which are used for conjugation, https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B5_%28%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%29 , that's how I see it (I might be wrong though).

Comment: @UVV I just gave the example of a passive participle in present tense used to refer to the past, and speculated it was why the OP was given the instruction "present or past active participle + main verb in past tense = actions take place at the same time" in his class. This instruction thus can be applied to passive participles, but not active ones.

Comment: @Vilmar I think I see what you mean. Still "Женщина, читающая книгу, жила в Москве" sounds like a valid sentence to me. Perhaps it might be not really correct in terms of grammar, but even if a verb is in the past tense, people would understand it as if it refers to present.

Comment: @UVV This sentence is of course valid, but the verb refers to the past. If one wanted to say that the woman lives in Moscow now as well, a present form of the verb would be used.

Answer (score 2):

The first one is the correct interpretation. To express the second one you would say "Женщина, **читавшая** книгу, жила в Москве".

Answer (score 1):

While generally the first interpretation is the correct one, it has to be remembered that there is such thing as 'historical present', when a narrator uses present when telling about past events. Though I may be mistaken, it seems to me that this rhetorical device tends to be used oftener in Russian than in English.

If this is the case, the sentence means, 'the woman who was reading the book had lived in Moscow' (the past tense is used for what happened before the time of narration). In my opinion, it would have its meaning clearer with 'прежде', 'раньше' or 'до того'.

For another thing, participles are not so extensively used in basic communications. Someone may feel confused by tenses and use them incorrectly or inconsistently. The sentence *might* be supposed to mean 'the woman who was reading the book was living in Moscow'; that's ungrammatical, of course, but not so severe an error.